# How can I hijack an opened browser session and attach it to the Webdriver than opening a browser by itself

Tags: java, selenium, browser, webdriver, session-hijacking

When using Selenium webDriver, I always have to initiate the driver and open a browser, navigate all the way through the flow to validate something, and if it failed throwing an exception, has to do the same spending lot of time.

Always thought of keeping another browser session opened, and let webdriver attached to the opened session and work on it, so the need to go through the flow could be eliminated.

Does any one knows how to do this in Selenium Webdriver, using Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this. It works for me.

```
public class xRemoteWebDriver : RemoteWebDriver
{
    public static bool newSession;
    public static string capPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "TestFiles", "tmp", "sessionCap");
    public static string sessiodIdPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "TestFiles", "tmp", "sessionid");

    public xRemoteWebDriver(Uri remoteAddress) 
        : base(remoteAddress, new DesiredCapabilities())
    {
    }

    protected override Response Execute(DriverCommand driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        if (driverCommandToExecute == DriverCommand.NewSession)
        {
            if (!newSession)
            {
                var capText = File.ReadAllText(capPath);
                var sidText = File.ReadAllText(sessiodIdPath);

                var cap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(capText);
                return new Response
                {
                    SessionId = sidText,
                    Value = cap
                };
            }
            else
            {
                var response = base.Execute(driverCommandToExecute, parameters);
                var dictionary = (Dictionary<string, object>) response.Value;
                File.WriteAllText(capPath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary));
                File.WriteAllText(sessiodIdPath, response.SessionId);
                return response;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var response = base.Execute(driverCommandToExecute, parameters);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.